# How to access and manipulate the files which on remote computer?

Tags: perl

I store some files on computer A , and I need computer B use some function like `open` `readline` `printf` to do some operations on the files of computer A .

But it seems I can only do the operation on local computer . So how to do ?

Comment: [`File::Remote`](http://search.cpan.org/~nwiger/File-Remote-1.17/Remote.pm); http://stackoverflow.com/q/11135588/139010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have ssh you can try [`Net::SSH::Expect`](http://search.cpan.org/~bnegrao/Net-SSH-Expect-1.09/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod). Otherwise [`File::Remote`](http://search.cpan.org/~nwiger/File-Remote-1.17/Remote.pm) could be an option as well.

Answer (score 1):

use [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-SFTP-Foreign).                    .